# wso2 das 3.0.1 with am 1.10.0: Cannot borrow client for ssl://localhost:7711

Tags: ssl, wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-das

I tried to set offset 3 and 0, all works fine with statistics with REST setup for now. However, the DAS wso2carbon.log keeps throwing the following error messages:

```
TID: [-1] [] [2016-09-15 16:27:30,727] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker} -  
Error while trying to connect to the endpoint. Cannot borrow client for ssl://localhost:7711  {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker}
org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointAuthenticationException: Cannot borrow client for ssl://localhost:7711
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.connect(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:100)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.run(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:43)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointSecurityException: Error while trying to connect to ssl://localhost:7711
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.thrift.ThriftSecureClientPoolFactory.createClient(ThriftSecureClientPoolFactory.java:61)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.client.AbstractClientPoolFactory.makeObject(AbstractClientPoolFactory.java:39)
    at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:1212)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.connect(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:92)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Could not connect to localhost on port 7711
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSSLTransportFactory.createClient(TSSLTransportFactory.java:212)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSSLTransportFactory.getClientSocket(TSSLTransportFactory.java:166)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.thrift.ThriftSecureClientPoolFactory.createClient(ThriftSecureClientPoolFactory.java:56)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:637)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.<init>(SSLSocketImpl.java:425)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(SSLSocketFactoryImpl.java:88)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSSLTransportFactory.createClient(TSSLTransportFactory.java:208)
    ... 11 more
```

I am wondering what caused this, and how to fix it?

Comment: what is DAS offset? 0 or 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I did is to remove port 7711 from data receiver config in apim admin-dashabord/Analytics. It is now only list tcp://localhost:7611 . That seems to fix it, but don't know why it did not respond at 7711 as it is actually configured in DAS conf/data-bridge/data-bridge-config.xml.

Comment: You will also get this exact error if the analytics module is not started when u start wso2 api manager server.

Comment: I will take a note of it. So next time I will make sure to start DAS first before starting APIM. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed any car files, you may need to update the port of receiver URL in scripts inside them, to match with your offset.

Comment: Thanks. Is 7711 the default port? I did not change ports in DAS right now. Its port offset is 0. Statistics is working in apim. I only have two capps installed. APIM rest works great, the other one - the sameple smart_home capp should also use the default 7711 port, right? (I did not make any changes to it)

Comment: If the port offset is 0, it should work. Can you telnet to it?