# WSO2 API Manager 2.0 Log Error localhost:7712 (ssl thrift port)

Tags: wso2, thrift, wso2-api-manager, wso2-das

I have installed APIM and APIM Analytics in two different machines. I followed [this guide](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Configuring+APIM+Analytics) to connect APIM to APIM Analytics. Analytics are working fine, I can see usage data in dashboards, but this error keeps showing once and again in log file

`ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker} -  Error while trying to connect to the endpoint. Cannot borrow client for ssl://localhost:7712 {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker}
org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointAuthenticationException: Cannot borrow client for ssl://localhost:7712`

I have changed `<DASAuthServerURL>{ssl://localhost:7712}</DASAuthServerURL>` in api-manager.xml values to the real machine IP and port, but it seems APIM is ignoring this param.

Is there any way to fix the error?

Comment: 1) In which server do you see the error logs?

2) Do you have a port offset in any of 2 servers?

Comment: I see errors in API Manager server log. Both servers have port offset 0, so API Manager Analytics is listening in default thrift ports (7611 and 7711). ¿Could it be that some CAR deployed in APIM by default is configured to point to localhost:7712?

Comment: Yes it can be due to a deployed car file. http://stackoverflow.com/a/39517097/805563

Comment: No car files deployed by default, so this can't be the reason.

Answer (score 4):

I encountered the same problem when trying to install APIM Analytics on a different server from APIM. Turns out I forgot to change the DAS_AGENT.url property in the [log4j.properties file](https://github.com/wso2/docker-apim/blob/2ac4c03455c53261654642418893d6992bd706ac/docker-compose/pattern-2/api-manager/carbon/repository/conf/log4j.properties#L190). Updating the property solved the issue.

Comment: Yes, I found it too some days ago. Maybe de online documentation should be changed to avoid this issues. If I don't want to use Log Analyzer I shouldn't have to configure it to stop logging errors. It's just my opinion.
Thanks for you help anyway

Answer (score 2):

> "Cannot borrow client for ssl://localhost:7712" "ThriftSecureClientPoolFactory"
>   Above is fixed by matching the ssl Thrift port defined in analytics worker `/conf/worker/deployment.yaml`

In wso2 api manger analytics 2.6.0 they made changes to DAS, now if you see this error you have to change `/repository/conf/api-manager.xml`

```
<StreamProcessorServerURL>{tcp://localhost:7612</StreamProcessorServerURL>
```

The ssl port 7712 is derived from `StreamProcessorServerURL:Port+100`
and

```
AuthUrlGroup>ssl://${carbon.local.ip}:7711</AuthUrlGroup>
```

The ssl port 7712 is derived from `AuthUrlGroup:Port`

Comment: what exactly needs to be changed? Change the port from 7612 to something else? If so, in that case, any changes will be required in `AuthUrlGroup` as you mentioned it's derived from earlier+100.

Could you please edit your answer with bit more clarification?