# WSO2 APIM Analytics server setup issue

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

In order to setup analytical server for API-Manager,i followed exactly same steps as specified in below wso2 documentation.
https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM220/Configuring+APIM+Analytics.

However i am facing below issues while running the API-M And API-Analytic instance.

> **WSO2 API-M**:
>   *[2018-05-08 02:52:05,378] ERROR - **DataEndpointConnectionWorker Error while trying to connect to the endpoint. Cannot borrow client
>   for ssl://localhost:7712**
>   org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointAuthenticationException:
>   Cannot borrow client for ssl://localhost:7712
>           at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.connect(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:99)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.run(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:42)
>           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointSecurityException:
>   Error while trying to connect to ssl://localhost:7712
>           at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.thrift.ThriftSecureClientPoolFactory.createClient(ThriftSecureClientPoolFactory.java:81)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.client.AbstractClientPoolFactory.makeObject(AbstractClientPoolFactory.java:39)
>           at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:1212)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.connect(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:91)
>           ... 7 more Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Could not connect to
>   localhost on port 7712
>           at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSSLTransportFactory.createClient(TSSLTransportFactory.java:237)
>           at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSSLTransportFactory.getClientSocket(TSSLTransportFactory.java:169)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.thrift.ThriftSecureClientPoolFactory.createClient(ThriftSecureClientPoolFactory.java:63)
>           ... 10 more Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
>           at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
>           at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
>           at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
>           at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
>           at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
>           at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
>           at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
>           at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
>           at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:618)
>           at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.(SSLSocketImpl.java:407)
>           at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(SSLSocketFactoryImpl.java:88)
>           at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSSLTransportFactory.createClient(TSSLTransportFactory.java:233)
>           ... 12 more [2018-05-08 02:52:34,371]  WARN - DataEndpointGroup No receiver is reachable at reconnection, will try
>   to reconnect every 30 sec [2018-05-08 02:52:35,378] ERROR -
>   DataEndpointConnectionWorker Error while trying to connect to
>   ssl://localhost:7712
>   org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointSecurityException:
>   Error while trying to connect to ssl://localhost:7712
>           at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.thrift.ThriftSecureClientPoolFactory.createClient(ThriftSecureClientPoolFactory.java:81)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.client.AbstractClientPoolFactory.makeObject(AbstractClientPoolFactory.java:39)
>           at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:1212)*
>
> **WSO2 API-Analytic:**
>   *JAVA_HOME environment variable is set to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25 CARBON_HOME environment variable is set to
>   C:\WSO2AM~4\WSO2AM~1\bin.. Loading spark environment variables
>   [2018-05-08 02:36:02,932]  INFO
>   {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Starting WSO2
>   Carbon... [2018-05-08 02:36:02,936]  INFO
>   {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Operating
>   System : Windows Server 2008 R2 6.1, amd64 [2018-05-08 02:36:02,936] 
>   INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Java Home 
>   : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre [2018-05-08 02:36:02,936] 
>   INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Java
>   Version     : 1.7.0_25 [2018-05-08 02:36:02,937]  INFO
>   {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Java VM
>
>   : Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 23.25-b01,Oracle Corporation
>   [2018-05-08 02:36:02,937]  INFO
>   {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Carbon Home
>
>   : C:\WSO2AM~4\WSO2AM~1\bin.. [2018-05-08 02:36:02,937]  INFO
>   {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Java Temp Dir
>
>   : C:\WSO2AM~4\WSO2AM~1\bin..\tmp [2018-05-08 02:36:02,937]  INFO
>   {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  User
>
>   : wsoadm_dev_svc, en-US, America/Los_Angeles [2018-05-08 02:36:03,570]
>   INFO
>   {org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.kafka.internal.ds.KafkaEventAdapterServiceDS}
>   -  Successfully deployed the Kafka output event adapto [2018-05-08 02:36:03,887]  INFO
>   {org.wso2.carbon.event.template.manager.core.internal.ds.TemplateDeployerServiceTrackerDS}
>   -  Successfully deployed the execution manager [2018-05-08 02:36:15,048]  INFO
>   {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.binary.internal.BinaryDataReceiver}
>   -  Started Binary SSL Transport on port : 9712 [2018-05-08 02:36:15,050]  INFO
>   {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.binary.internal.BinaryDataReceiver}
>   -  Started Binary TCP Transport on port : 9612 [2018-05-08 02:36:15,207]  INFO
>   {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.internal.DataBridgeDS} - 
>   Successfully deployed Agent Server [2018-05-08 02:36:15,388]  INFO
>   {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistryService} - 
>   Configured Registry in 64ms [2018-05-08 02:36:15,912]  INFO
>   {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.internal.RegistryCoreServiceComponent}
>   -  Registry Mode    : READ-WRITE [2018-05-08 02:36:22,854]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.metrics.impl.util.JmxReporterBuilder} -  Creating JMX
>   reporter for Metrics with domain 'org.wso2.carbon.metrics' [2018-05-08
>   02:36:22,861]  INFO
>   {org.wso2.carbon.metrics.impl.util.JDBCReporterBuilder} -  Creating
>   JDBC reporter for Metrics with source 'SOADEVV001', data source 'jdbc/
>   [2018-05-08 02:36:22,862]  INFO
>   {org.wso2.carbon.metrics.impl.reporter.AbstractReporter} -  Started
>   JMX reporter for Metrics [2018-05-08 02:36:22,870]  INFO
>   {org.wso2.carbon.metrics.impl.reporter.AbstractReporter} -  Started
>   JDBC reporter for Metrics [2018-05-08 02:36:26,352]  INFO
>   {org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.solr.SolrClient} -  Default
>   Embedded Solr Server Initialized [2018-05-08 02:36:27,524]  INFO
>   {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.UserStoreMgtDSComponent} -  Carbon
>   UserStoreMgtDSComponent activated successfully.
>   **[2018-05-08 02:37:32,134]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager} -  Carbon
>   initialization is delayed due to the following unsatisfied items:
>   [2018-05-08 02:37:32,498]  WARN
>   {org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager} -  Waiting for
>   required OSGi Service: org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisObserver
>   [2018-05-08 02:38:32,135]  WARN
>   {org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager} -  Carbon
>   initialization is delayed due to the following unsatisfied items:***

**Note**:I am using same Machine for both API-M and API API-Analytic instance.
For APIM Offset is set to 0 and for API-Analytic it is 1.
I am using default H2 DB for for both.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Format error message

Comment: Have you tried the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/39907842/1008424