# Cannot borrow client for ssl://das_server:7712

Tags: ssl, wso2, wso2-api-manager, ibm-api-management

I´m trying to configure DAS server with my Gateway wso2 API Management.

In my log always appear the messages bellow:

```
TID: [-1] [] [2017-04-24 19:55:11,133] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker} -  Error while trying to connect to the endpoint. Cannot borrow client for ssl://das_server:7712 {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker}
org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointAuthenticationException: Cannot borrow client for ssl://das_server:7712
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.connect(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:100)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.run(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:43)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointAuthenticationException: Thrift exception
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.thrift.ThriftDataEndpoint.login(ThriftDataEndpoint.java:50)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.connect(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:94)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:129)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:86)
        at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readAll(TBinaryProtocol.java:429)
        at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readI32(TBinaryProtocol.java:318)
        at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readMessageBegin(TBinaryProtocol.java:219)
        at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:69)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.commons.thrift.service.secure.ThriftSecureEventTransmissionService$Client.recv_connect(ThriftSecureEventTransmissionService.java:110)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.commons.thrift.service.secure.ThriftSecureEventTransmissionService$Client.connect(ThriftSecureEventTransmissionService.java:96)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.thrift.ThriftDataEndpoint.login(ThriftDataEndpoint.java:46)
        ... 7 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
        at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
        at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:973)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:930)
        at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:105)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:127)
        ... 15 more
```

Does someone have an idea about this error?

My architecture is distributed components

Comment: Looks like your server can't access the url: ssl://das_server:7712. Can you telnet to the host and port?

telnet das_server 7712

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for response. Yes. I can connect with the ip:port.

Comment: telnet das_server 7712
Trying 10.30.20.10...
Connected to das_server.
Escape character is '^]'.

Comment: A similar issue is reported here. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39516533/wso2-das-3-0-1-with-am-1-10-0-cannot-borrow-client-for-ssl-localhost7711

Looks like you have started APIM before starting DAS?

Comment: Thanks a lot  Anuruddha,

Comment: I will to test..

Comment: Hi Anuruddha I tested but appear the same problem yet.

Comment: TID: [-1] [] [2017-04-26 10:33:17,983] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpoint} -  Unable to send events to the endpoint.  {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpoint}
org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointException: **Cannot send Events**

Comment: Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: **Read timed out**
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:129)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:86)
        at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readAll(TBinaryProtocol.java:429)
        at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readI32(TBinaryProtocol.java:318)
        at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readMessageBegin(TBinaryProtocol.java:219)

Comment: The errror **Read timed out** appear all the time that Gateway and DAS are Up. Are you have a sugestion?

Comment: Make sure usernames and passwords are correct in the file <API-M_HOME>/repository/conf/api-manager.xml under <Analytics> section and the firewall isn't breaking any connections. https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Configuring+APIM+Analytics#93cf2fbc08914568b6e459d182323090

Comment: Thanks Anuruddha. In this case I using DAS and not Analytics. I will review the instalation DAS Server. Thanks a lot to the informations.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure to add the GW certificate to the client-trustore.jks of the DAS server. This can be the issue which is not trusting your GW from the DAS server.